I am curious about the implementation of ItemDetailPage calling api with axios
Implementing ItemDetailPage using axios to call http://localhost:5001/products/${id} API. Cannot destructure property 'prodImageURL' of 'product' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'prodImageURL' of 'product' as it is null. An error appears
ItemDetail.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"; 

function ItemDetailPage() {
  const { id} = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null); 
  const { prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price } = product;
  console.log("prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price",prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price);
  const imgURL_full = `http://localhost:5001/${prodImageURL}`; 
  console.log("product", product);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/products/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setProduct(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [id]); 

  if (!product) {
    return <div>삼품이 없습니다</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='detail-info'>
      <img src={imgURL_full} alt={name} />
      <div className='detail-text'>
          <p className='detail-title'>{name}</p>
          <p className='detail-funding'>펀딩 진행중:{funding}</p>
          <p className='detail-personnel'>펀딩 인원:{personnel}</p>
          <p>가격: {price}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
       </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetailPage;


product is null initially. So how do you expect it to have the property prodImageURL?

You error should come up before you are making an api call as you are setting product as null in useState and then trying to read product.something. Nothing to do with api call.

Null value never be destructured. Please initialize the initial value :
const initalValue={name: "",  .................} and then the use initialValue as default of product state : const [product, setProduct] = useState(initalValue);

The error is happening because you don't have the product data while you are destructuring. You can fix this by moving the destructuring part below the return so that the code won't be reached before product value is set. As:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function ItemDetailPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5001/products/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setProduct(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [id]);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>삼품이 없습니다</div>;
  }

  const { prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price } = product;
  const imgURL_full = `http://localhost:5001/${prodImageURL}`;
  console.log("product", product);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="detail-info">
        <img src={imgURL_full} alt={name} />
        <div className="detail-text">
          <p className="detail-title">{name}</p>
          <p className="detail-funding">펀딩 진행중:{funding}</p>
          <p className="detail-personnel">펀딩 인원:{personnel}</p>
          <p>가격: {price}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetailPage;


http://localhost:5001/products/undefined 404 (Not Found)
Axios Error Occurs

what is the output of console.log("product", product); ?

console.log(" prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price:", prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price); I tried changing it to check the console.

@조민성 what is the output? please add the screenshot of browser console by editing the question.

Please implement InitialValue:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from "axios"; 

const initialValue={
name:"", 
funding:"", 
personnel:"", 
price:0,
prodImageURL:"", 
}
    
    function ItemDetailPage() {
      const { id} = useParams();
      const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialValue); 
      const { prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price } = product;
      console.log("prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price",prodImageURL, name, funding, personnel, price);
      const imgURL_full = `http://localhost:5001/${prodImageURL}`; 
      console.log("product", product);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/products/${id}`)
          .then((response) => {
            setProduct(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }, [id]); 
    
      if (!product) {
        return <div>삼품이 없습니다</div>;
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div className='detail-info'>
          <img src={imgURL_full} alt={name} />
          <div className='detail-text'>
              <p className='detail-title'>{name}</p>
              <p className='detail-funding'>펀딩 진행중:{funding}</p>
              <p className='detail-personnel'>펀딩 인원:{personnel}</p>
              <p>가격: {price}</p>
          </div>
          </div>
           </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default ItemDetailPage;


[![The product image does not appear on the ItemDetailPage screen.][1]: https://i.sstatic.net/OSifVK18.png
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";



function ItemDetailPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/products/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setProduct(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [id]);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>삼품이 없습니다</div>;
  }

  const { prodImageURL, prodname, funding, personnel, prodprice } = product;
  const imgURL_full = `http://localhost:5001/${prodImageURL}`;
  console.log("product",product);
  console.log("prodImageURL, prodname, funding, personnel, prodprice"
    ,prodImageURL, prodname, funding, personnel, prodprice);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="detail-info">
        <img src={imgURL_full} alt={prodname} />
        <div className="detail-text">
          <p className="detail-title">{prodname}</p>
          <p className="detail-funding">펀딩 진행중:{funding}</p>
          <p className="detail-personnel">펀딩 인원:{personnel}</p>
          <p>가격: {prodprice}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetailPage;

